# How to initiate syncing

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have got a few directories I use daily and I would like to sync them with ubuntu one. But if I mark these directories only an OK flag is shown on the directory icon but nothing more happens. I realized if I copy files inside of the folder they get synced..

Thus I used touch on other files but nothing happen. How can I initiate syncing of such folders?

Comment: So files already _inside_ the folder when you checked the box did not sync? This was an old issue? What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to do aything, since Ubuntu One is supposed to detect when a file changes. Touch, however, doesn't change the file contents, and Ubuntu One doesn't track metadata (like modification dates) so it doesn't do aything.

Answer (score 1):

This also looks like a bug [LP:869920](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/869920) we are currently working on. When you mark the folder to be synced it does not currently work immediately. The synchronization software makrs the folder to be synced, but ignores the content until client restart.

The synchronization will work correctly when you restart the client completely (e.g. with the following in the terminal):

```
u1sdtool --quit
u1sdtool --start
```